# How to properly understand the carriage return (a.k.a. \r)?

Tags: c++, loops, carriage-return

I have seen this carriage return example online about a loading effect but I am failing to understand it properly. Why does it have to be 2 `\rLoading` and not one? Can someone explain it to me?

```
for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
  cout << "\rLoading   \rLoading";
  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << ".";
    sleep(300);
  }
}
```

Comment: The point of the example is to *demonstrate* what the `\r` character does: you only see *one* "Loading" because the `\r` returns to the beginning of the line and overwrites what is already on that line.

Comment: @AdrianMole but which of the `\rLoading` does that? the first or second one in the `cout` statement

Comment: See the answer by @Ctx, which explains things very well.

Comment: It is an anachronism. A typewriter had a large rubber roller against which the sheet of paper was wrapped. The roller was held in a fixed positon. The *carriage* (the movable part of the typewriter containing the typewriter-tape hit by the keys to create characters). The *carriage-return* was the lever on the right side of the carriage that caused the carriage to return all the way to the left margin of the paper to begin the next line. The software `'\r'` in effect does the same thing, it returns the position for the next character output to the beginning of the line.

Comment: It is also somewhat terminal dependent. Some of the original teletype control characters (tab, newline, and this carriage return) have been interpreted pretty consistently ever since the mechanical era; others, like form feed or vertical tab, are less canonical. But it's important to understand that it is a *terminal convention* which just happens to work fairly universally. As an exception, Mac OS before OS X would perform a newline operation upon receiving a carriage return, i.e. it used `'\r'` instead of `'\n'` to identify the line end.

Answer (score 5):

The first section

```
\rLoading____
```

is printed to have the string "Loading" and three empty spaces at the beginning of the line. The next carriage return then sets the cursor to the beginning of the line. Then

```
Loading
```

is printed again, but the cursor is now directly behind the word, at the first of the three spaces. Now here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  cout << ".";
  sleep(300);
}
```

three dots are printed in an interval of 300 seconds each into the places, where the three dots are.

This whole procedure is iterated three times, so the main purpose of the three blanks of the first "Loading" is, to delete the dots from the previous iteration.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that `\r` will not clear characters which were printed on the screen earlier. So the first `\rLoading`    act as a display eraser.
In fact you can use 10 spaces instead of the `Loading`   , but you must count it accurately, which is not intuitional.
The following is the optimized code, which can be directly compiled and run on an modern x86 & linux machine. You can try to delete one of the `\rLoading` and see what will happen for easily understanding.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
    std::cout << "\rLoading   \rLoading" << std::flush;
 // std::cout << "\r          \rLoading" << std::flush; // same effect
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      std::cout << "." << std::flush;
      sleep(1);
    }
  }
  std::cout << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Two promotions:

- a std::flush is needed or you will not see the effects
- 300 seconds is too long -> 1 seconds